# ffmpeg loudnorm filter does not make audio louder

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm new to the loudnorm filter. I have successfully used it to make a file quieter, but I can't get it to make one louder.

Pass 1 command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -af loudnorm=I=-16:TP=-1.5:LRA=11:print_format=json -f null -
```

Output:

```
{
        "input_i" : "-23.54",
        "input_tp" : "-7.96",
        "input_lra" : "0.00",
        "input_thresh" : "-34.17",
        "output_i" : "-23.09",
        "output_tp" : "-7.51",
        "output_lra" : "0.00",
        "output_thresh" : "-33.72",
        "normalization_type" : "linear",
        "target_offset" : "7.09"
}
```

Pass 2 command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.wav -af loudnorm=I=-16:TP=-1.5:LRA=11:measured_I=-23.54:measured_TP=-7.96:measured_LRA=0.00:measured_thresh=-34.17:offset=7.09:linear=true:print_format=summary -ar 16k out.wav
```

Output:

```
Input Integrated:    -23.5 LUFS
Input True Peak:      -8.0 dBTP
Input LRA:             0.0 LU
Input Threshold:     -34.2 LUFS

Output Integrated:   -23.1 LUFS
Output True Peak:     -7.5 dBTP
Output LRA:            0.0 LU
Output Threshold:    -33.7 LUFS

Normalization Type:   Linear
Target Offset:        +7.1 LU
```

I expected the output numbers to be close to the specified values, for example, `Output Integrated: -16.0 LUFS`. Why is that not the case?

Update: If I peak normalize `in.wav` the measured `input_i` is -15.55. Applying loudnorm to that file gives the expected output. So loudnorm will make the loud file quieter, but not the quiet file louder.

Comment: There's something else going on; I can make outputs louder. The output I is not guaranteed but output TP is, and I can confirm that in my test. Can you share the audio?

Comment: A sample file can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V4PYdidoTP_nh70ft4shImZMU_D27gOb

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The loudnorm filter uses (overlapping) windows of 3 seconds of audio to calculate short-term loudness in the source and adjust the destination to meet the target parameters. The sample file is only a second long, which looks to be the reason for the anomalous normalization.

If I pad the audio to 3 seconds and run,

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -af apad,atrim=0:3,loudnorm=I=-16:TP=-1.5:LRA=11:measured_I=-23.54:measured_TP=-7.96:measured_LRA=0.00:measured_thresh=-34.17:offset=7.09:linear=true:print_format=summary -ar 16k pad-out.wav
```

loudnorm works as expected.

```
Input Integrated:    -23.8 LUFS
Input True Peak:      -8.0 dBTP
Input LRA:             0.2 LU
Input Threshold:     -36.0 LUFS

Output Integrated:   -15.9 LUFS
Output True Peak:     -1.5 dBTP
Output LRA:            0.0 LU
Output Threshold:    -26.7 LUFS

Normalization Type:   Dynamic
Target Offset:        -0.1 LU
```

To recover the original length, you can run the above command with a trim filter at the end

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -af apad,atrim=0:3,loudnorm=I=-16:TP=-1.5:LRA=11:measured_I=-23.54:measured_TP=-7.96:measured_LRA=0.00:measured_thresh=-34.17:offset=7.09:linear=true:print_format=summary,atrim=0:1.0 -ar 16k trimmed-out.wav
```

where the 2nd argument to atrim is the original duration, in seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the workaround, which seems quite effective.

Some experiments show that the final result is more accurate if you pad in the Pass 1 step too.

Comment: Just an observation linked to the above comment: without adding padding in the Pass 1, the result can be not only less accurate (in terms of loudness) but also distorted (kind of a choppy sound). Be careful here :)