# FFmpeg loudnorm: what does dynamic mode mean?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have numerous audios that i'd like to normalize by the same reference with FFmpeg loudnorm filter. But every time I do the 1st pass of normalization, normalization type reverts to "dynamic".

From [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1281327/ffmpeg-loudnorm-filter-does-not-make-audio-louder) I know, that the loudnorm filter uses windows of 3 seconds of audio to calculate short-term loudness in the source and adjust the destination to meet the target parameters. As most of my files are shotert than 3 seconds, I have to add some silence to them to make files at least 3 seconds long.

Knowing that I do the 1st pass, but it reverts to dynamic mode (Normalization Type: Dynamic) every time

Pass 1

```
ffmpeg -i input.ogg -af apad,atrim=0:3,loudnorm=I=-17.2:TP=-2:LRA=7:print_format=summary -f null -
```

I get

```
Input Integrated:    -17.4 LUFS
Input True Peak:      -0.9 dBTP
Input LRA:             0.3 LU
Input Threshold:     -28.9 LUFS

Output Integrated:   -16.1 LUFS
Output True Peak:     -2.0 dBTP
Output LRA:            0.0 LU
Output Threshold:    -27.2 LUFS

Normalization Type:   Dynamic
Target Offset:        -1.1 LU
```

FFmpeg documentation says "*Target LRA shouldn’t be lower than source LRA and the change in integrated loudness shouldn’t result in a true peak which exceeds the target TP. If any of these conditions aren’t met, normalization mode will revert to dynamic. Options are true or false. Default is true.*"

As I can see, none of these conditions are met, but normalization type still gets reverted to "dynamic". As an experiment I tried to change my target integrated loudness, TP and LRA in all different ways, but i still get normalization type "dynamic" every time

1. Does it mean that "dynamic mode" applies instead of "linear mode" when I do the 2nd step (actual normalization)?
2. What does this "dynamic type" mean, and how is it different from "linear"?
3. Why this even happens and what do I do wrong?

Comment: Share the command and log for 2nd pass.

Comment: Please focus on a single question. This site answers single questions with single answers. You can post multiple questions at a time, as separate questions.